# Django server response with 4xx response code sometimes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

**Background Information :**

1. I have developed server in django python and deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk by using ELB.
2. Server content many API named like as /testapi, /xyz, etc.

**Problem Facing :**

Sometime it gave me 4xx or 200 when i called /testapi.

Attaching logs of AWS EC2 instant which show some of request are failed with 4xx response code and some are ok i.e 200.

Please guide me on the right path so I can solve it.

**-----------------------Start of code-------------------**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def get_profile_details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            logger = logging.getLogger("oauth")
            logger.info("get_profile_details POST endpoint called.")
            data = dict()

            client_id = request.data.get(UiString.client_id)
            client_secret = request.data.get(UiString.client_secret)

            logger.info("get_profile_details : client_id = " + client_id)
            logger.info("get_profile_details : client_secret = " + client_secret)

            if helper.validateClientIdAndClientSecret(client_id, client_secret):
                logger.info("get_profile_details : Invalid Client Credentials")
                return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.Fail, "Unauthorized access", {}, False, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

            try:
                type = request.data.get(UiString.type)
                email = request.data.get(UiString.email)
                mobile = request.data.get(UiString.mobile)
                username = request.data.get(UiString.username)



                if helper.isNullOrEmpty(type):
                    return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.missing_required_param, "Type should not be null", data, False,
                                                 status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

                if type == 'email' and helper.isNullOrEmpty(email):
                    return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.missing_required_param, "Email should not be null", data, False,
                                                 status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                elif type == 'mobile' and helper.isNullOrEmpty(mobile):
                    return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.missing_required_param, "Mobile should not be null", data, False,
                                                 status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                elif type == 'username' and helper.isNullOrEmpty(username):
                    return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.missing_required_param, "Username should not be null", data,
                                                 False, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

                try:
                    # Check user detail based on type
                    if type == 'email':
                        logger.info("get_profile_details : by using email as type")
                        user_details = User.objects.get(email=email)
                        user_profile_detail = user_details.user_profile
                    elif type == 'username':
                        logger.info("get_profile_details : by using username as type")
                        user_details = User.objects.get(username=username)
                        user_profile_detail = user_details.user_profile
                    elif type == 'mobile':
                        logger.info("get_profile_details : by using mobile as type")
                        user_profile_detail = UserProfile.objects.get(mobile1=mobile)
                        #user_details = User.objects.get(pk=user_profile_detail.user_id)
                except (UserProfile.DoesNotExist, User.DoesNotExist) as ex:
                    logger.info("get_profile_details : user does not exist")
                    logger.exception(ex)
                    return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.user_does_not_exist, "user does not exist",
                                                 data,
                                                 False, status.HTTP_200_OK)
                except Exception as ex:
                    logger.info("get_profile_details : Got a exception")
                    logger.exception(ex)
                    return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.exception_in_finding_user, "Got a exception",
                                                 data,
                                                 False, status.HTTP_200_OK)

                user = user_profile_detail.user
                user_profile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user.user_profile)
                logger.info("get_profile_details : Got user detail : " + user.username)

                data[UiString.user] = {

                    UiString.email : user.email,
                    UiString.username : user.username,
                    UiString.first_name : user.first_name,
                    UiString.last_name : user.last_name,
                    UiString.user_profile : user_profile_serializer.data,
                }
                logger.info("get_profile_details : User details retrived successfully")
                return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.success, "User details retrived successfully",
                                             data,
                                             False, status.HTTP_200_OK)

            except Exception as ex:
                logger.info("get_profile_details : Exception in finding user")
                logger.exception(ex)
                return helper.returnResponse(ResponseCodes.exception_in_finding_user, "Exception in finding user detail api",
                                             data,
                                             False, status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except:
            response = helper.generateStandardResponse(ResponseCodes.exception_in_finding_user, "Failed get user from db. Something went wrong.", data,
                                                       False);
            return Response(response, status.HTTP_417_EXPECTATION_FAILED)
    return Response("Method not allowed.", status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

**--------------------Start Of Logs -------------------**

```
172.31.16.19 - - [28/Oct/2017:12:01:59 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 404 218 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 - - [28/Oct/2017:12:02:01 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 404 218 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 - - [28/Oct/2017:12:02:09 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 404 218 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:02:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:02:44 +0000] "PUT /xyz/ HTTP/1.1" 200 872 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.16.19 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:02:54 +0000] "PUT /xyz/ HTTP/1.1" 200 834 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:23 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 866 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.16.19 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:25 +0000] "PUT /xyz/ HTTP/1.1" 200 857 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
::1 (-) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:33 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 (-) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:34 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 (-) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:44 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 (-) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:45 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 (internal dummy connection)"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:03:51 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 906 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.16.19 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:04:03 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 884 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:04:08 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 904 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:04:30 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 (52.66.89.157) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:05:17 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1268 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.16.19 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:05:33 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 861 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.16.19 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:05:48 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 400 88 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:05:53 +0000] "POST /testapi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
172.31.2.71 (35.154.225.66) - - [28/Oct/2017:12:06:11 +0000] "PUT /xyz/ HTTP/1.1" 200 830 "http://192.168.0.167/" "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
```

Comment: Post your code that responds to a `POST` to `/testapi/` please. I've seen an ELB setup cause a 504, and you would expect to look at the AWS setup for 5xx errors, but 4xx is an application level error.

Comment: agree with @markwalker_

Comment: @markwalker_  I had update the question with code please check and let me know is there wrong. Thanks for showing your interest in my problem.

Comment: @HrushikeshShinde ok, so looking at all of your return points, none raise a 404. Therefore a callable or something being triggered through there must raise it.